# My program immediately crashes upon execution

Tags: c++

My program is below, every time i run it, it immediately crashes and I don't understand why, can anyone help? Its meant to be a map where someone can move around the @ character with the arrow keys, but i mucked it up somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

char Map[20][40] = {"***************************************",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*                                     *",
                    "*@                                    *",
                    "***************************************"};

int Gamespeed = 100;
int Level = 0;
bool stopgame = false;

int main()
{
    while(stopgame == false)
    {
        system("cls");

        for(int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
            cout << Map[y] << endl;

        for(int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
        {

            for(int x = 0; x < 20; y++)
            {

                switch(Map[y][x])
                {
                case'@':
                {
                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                    {
                        int y2 = (y - 1);

                        switch(Map[y2][x]){

                        case' ':
                        {
                            Map[y][x] = ' ';
                            y -= 1;
                            Map[y2][x] = '@';
                        }
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
                    {
                        int y2 = (y + 1);

                        switch(Map[y2][x]){

                        case' ':
                        {
                            Map[y][x] = ' ';
                            y += 1;
                            Map[y2][x] = '@';
                        }
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
                    {
                        int x2 = (x + 1);

                        switch(Map[y][x2]){

                        case' ':
                        {
                            Map[y][x] = ' ';
                            x += 1;
                            Map[y][x2] = '@';
                        }
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
                    {
                        int x2 = (x - 1);

                        switch(Map[y][x2]){

                        case' ':
                        {
                            Map[y][x] = ' ';
                            x -= 1;
                            Map[y][x2] = '@';
                        }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Sleep(Gamespeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: well for one you have `y` and `x` switched around.

Comment: Could you be more specific? In a multidimensional array, the first bracket denotes vertical position and the second denotes horizontal position, so where are they switched?

Comment: Crashes where?  Your debugger should be point at a line where the crash occured.  This generally shows you where you wrote beyond the end of an array.

Comment: You declared it as a map[20][40], however, you are iterating over 40 in the first dimension and 20 in the second.  This will not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some pity.

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                    {
                        int y2 = (y - 1);

                        switch(Map[y2][x]){
...
```

Notice that you subtract 1 from y, but what if y is already 0?  Boom - you just read outside of your array.

Worse:

```
Map[y2][x] = '@';
```

Writes to la-la land in those cases and is probably what is generating the exception.

Same mistake around each edge.  You have to range check your values before peeking into your array.  There may be more issues, but this one really is glaring.

Comment: The bounds checking I can fix, as for Map[y2][x] = '@'; that only occurs if that space was previously empty and the map is bordered. My real issue is that windows informs me that the .exe has stopped working every time i run the program, meanwhile my compiler reports no issues. I did try to ensure I left space for the null char in the array initialization. Any help would be really appreciated. I didn't expect to come to a Q&A site looking for help only to find mostly scorn and downvotes, you're like the only one who has genuinely offered help.

Comment: Then you need to learn to use your debugger to show you where to problem area is next.  If you can open you program in your debugger and run it, it should stop on the line where things have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Printing `40` elements of a `20` element array is undefined behaviour.

```
 char Map[20][40];
 for(int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
    cout << Map[y] << endl;
```

Map is an array with `20` elements, each of which is an array of `40` char.

This is just one example in your code of using array indices and dimensions in the wrong order.